# Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Producer which writes data onto the topic with an Avro Schema. The Kafka HDFS Connect sinks the data from the topic to the hdfs as parquet format and creates external table in Hive. Works fine in Hive/Impala engines. So far so good. We cannot control the Producer side Avro schema column ordering. When there is a change in the avro schema order of columns on the Producer side then error comes up in Hive.

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveArrayInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector
```

Note: Impala is still fine even when the AVRO schema column order changes.